# Can initialization expressions be used for constructors in Java like in C++?

Tags: java, c++, constructor

I know that in C++, class constructors can be written with initialization expressions in this form:

```
class-name(parameters) : initialization-expressions { body }
```

Is there some sort of analog to this in Java? If not, then why not? Because I know that in C++, initialization expressions make constructor calls more efficient. Is such an efficiency-booster overlooked by Java's design, or is it just unnecessary?

Comment: haha i guess so. silly me!

Comment: Java in general (at least, in my view) tends to prefer keeping a smaller syntax and not having that many ways to solve the same language-level problem. We just now got lambdas in Java 8, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary purpose of C++ initialization lists is not efficiency, it is for initializing the members correctly (because otherwise default initialization will be used, which may be either undesirable, or impossible). If there is any efficiency gained, it is due to eliminating unnecessary expensive default construction operations which you plan to undo in the constructor body. Java doesn't initialize member objects before the constructor body, other than setting them to Null. Even as a mainly C++ guy, I would freely admit that complicating the language for such a micro-optimization is not worth it.

Comment: Which constructor is called is determined by the arguments, not the initializers that follow them. The main purpose as far as I know is initializer `const` members, which can't be assigned.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: The initialization list is for calling the correct constructors of the member objects. The const ones and the non-const ones. It just so happens that const members (and reference members, and members without default constructors) absolutely *need* the initialization list.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of initialization is not necessary in Java, because Java has no embedded member objects. Objects consist of primitive fields and reference fields. Java will never implicitly call default constructors on objects (which C++ does if you don't initialize a member object in the member initialization list).